# Hot Network Question titles are interpreted as LaTeX / MathJax?

Tags: bug, design

I noticed when viewing a question here that a hot network question from Money.SE was formatted strangely. Presumably because it's interpreting the title as math markup.

Screenshot from this site:

[image]

Screenshot from another site:

[image]

Comment: Indeed it looks that way. Money.SE probably does not use MathJax/LaTex, given the prevalence of the dollar sign there. It all depends on your point (or site) of view I guess...

Comment: @JonCuster correct, to my knowledge they don't use the formatting there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [known issue](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229363/exclude-tex-se-question-titles-from-mathjax-parsing-in-hot-network-questions). As a workaround, you can install [SOUP](https://stackapps.com/questions/4486/the-stack-overflow-unofficial-patch-soup) (Stack Overflow Unofficial Patch), which will prevent MathJax rendering in HNQ titles unless the site is known to have MathJax enabled.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to search for this on meta and didn't find it. In any case, it's nowhere close to being enough o fan issue that I'd install a workaround; I just wanted to report it.

Comment: OK, cool, and thanks. Though note that SOUP also fixes a lot of other little issues with the sites, so I'd recommend it to everyone.

Comment: Interesting, I hadn't heard of it before, I'll have a look.